# Get last id MAX(message_id) in Group by

Tags: php, max

I'm trying to get the last id in my database to print out the new data into my div. Its not updating the new data with the last added content by message_id. The last query works and inserts the ex amount of 'NEW MESSAGES' into the same div so I presume its something to do with how my first query is structured. I used MAX but it isn't working.

I'm pretty sure as I've grouped messages together I need to get the max id of each group and not the complete table. So how would I go about doing this?

```
  $user1_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
            $callmessage="SELECT MAX(message_id) AS message_id,message_content,message_target,message_status,message_creator,message_throughurl,message_time FROM messages WHERE message_target='$user1_id' OR message_creator='$user1_id' AND message_status='1' OR message_status='2'
            Group By 

           (if(message_target > message_creator,  message_creator,message_target))
           ,(if(message_creator > message_target,  message_target,message_creator))

            ORDER BY message_id DESC ";
            $chantmessage=mysqli_query($mysqli,$callmessage) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $nummessage=mysqli_num_rows($chantmessage);

            if($nummessage==0){
            echo"No Messages";
            }else{
            while($message=mysqli_fetch_array($chantmessage))
            {
            if($message['message_creator']==$_SESSION['id'] || $message['message_target']==$_SESSION['id']){
            ?>

            <div class="notif_uimessage">
            <div class="notif_textmessage">

            <div id="notif_actual_textmessage-<? echo $message['message_id'] ?>" class="notif_actual_textmessage">
            <?
            $string=$message['message_content'];
            $truncated = (strlen($string) > 30) ? substr($string, 0, 30) . '...' : $string;
            $data=rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($message['message_creator']);
            $data2=rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($message['message_target']);
             echo "<img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$message['message_creator'].".jpg?photo_time=" . time()."\" onerror='this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><br />".$data['fullname']." >>  ".$data2['fullname']."<a class='markasreadmessage' href='".$message['message_throughurl']." '>".$truncated." </a><br />";
            echo "<abbr class='timeago' title='".$message['message_time']."'>".$message['message_time']."</abbr> - ";

            $sqlsmessage=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from messages WHERE message_creator=".$message['message_creator']." AND message_target=".$message['message_target']." AND message_status='1'");
                    $messages_count=mysqli_num_rows($sqlsmessage);
                    if($messages_count==0)
                    {
                    echo'No New Messages';
                    }else if($message_count>0)
                    {   
                    echo '<span class="newmessagescount">'.$messages_count.' NEW</span>';
                    }
            ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <?  }}}?>
```

Comment: What's your first and last query? I'm seeing only the one you are saving into `$callmessage`. Please clarify that.

Comment: `$callmessage` and `$sqlsmessage` @PatrickG